# AC Nanovoltmeter for Arduino alike?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, voltage-measurement, esp32

I have searched across web, but I am unable to find such a circuit.

- I am looking for a circuit of a AC nano-voltmeter in range 5-10 to 100 nV which output is suitable to be handled by some precise ADC like ADS1252 ( which will be later interfaced by Arduino or ESP8266 or ESP32 ).

The signal is in frequency range of 10 to 4000 Hz.

A precision of 2 to 5 nV would be sufficient.

The signal is coming from a coil without core, it gain signal from another coil, which change frequency. (I can make it static frequency on about 1000 Hz if this makes the things easy.)
The impedance of the source coil is about 1-2 ohms. The current is considerable small - a few nanoampers I presume (I am unable to measure it).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102904/discussion-on-question-by-nik-lozan-ac-nanovoltmeter-for-arduino-alike). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 3):

> The signal is in frequency range of 10 to 4000 Hz.
>   A precision of 2 to 5 nV would be sufficient.

Uh, good luck with that.

Thermal noise power at room temperature is

$$N = k_B T B\text, $$

with \$k_B\$ being the Boltzmann constant, \$T\$ absolute temperature, and \$B\$ bandwidth.

To observe your 4 kHz signal, you'll need a 4 kHz bandwidth (=9 dBHz) (you'll actually need more – but let's not get into Nyquist and practicality here).

That leaves us with -203 dBW/Hz + 6 dBHz = -197 dBW. Over a 200 Ω measurement load (can't go lower, or else your measurement will be skewed by the load), due to \$P= U^2 \cdot R\$, that leaves us with

$$U= \sqrt{RP} = \sqrt{200\cdot 10^{-19.7}}\text{ V}\approx 0.2\text{ nV}\text,$$

and that's assuming the least possible measurement impedance, *perfect* filterig to reduce the bandwidth to 8 kHz, AND an amplifier noise that has a 0 dB noise figure (which doesn't exist). Notice that this is the thermal noise voltage standard deviation – you'll need to compare that with your required measurement accuracy yourself, you haven't told us.

Realistically, your noise standard deviation would be somewhere in the range of 20 to 1000 nV, even if you built this expertly. But then, external noise sources come very much into play – there's positively very hard work to be done to shield this circuit from all EMI, **especially** if you want to connect it to a microcontroller (hint: don't, keep your high-frequency switching as far as possible from this).

All in all, this is a project you won't be able to succeed with.

Comment: Great explanation Marcus ! Thank You ! I really could not believed at first that there is not any kind of IC ready to meet these requirements, and to be honest I were expecting some sort of accessible IC which fit them. It is a bit of disappointment that there is not such thing yet. :'(

Comment: as I tried to explain, this has nothing to do with "there is no such IC yet"; it's physically impossible to get any better than this. So there *can't* be any chip that has less standard deviation than what I calculated. It's impossible. Also, all external noise sources will be much higher – so how would having an IC solve that? you're not putting much thought into what you' want to do here!